# If basis $\beta$ is orthonormal, then $\beta^{*}=\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite inner product space. Suppose that  $\beta$ is orthonormal basis of $V$. How do I show that $\beta^{*}=\beta$? 
Where $\beta^{*}$ is dual basis of $\beta$

Dual basis definition:

For all $v_i\in\beta$ and $v_j^{*}\in\beta^{*}$, the inner product $\langle v_i,v^{*}_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$

Comment: Doesn't that follow directly from the definition? I can't even see that there is something to prove here. (And on a side note, please use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$. The relation symbols `<` and `>` not only look different, they result in wrong spacing too.)

Comment: maybe is the hour... IDK! :(

Comment: I rather suspect part of the problem lies in bad notation. Which isn't your fault, presumably. To be more precise, a basis ought to be thought of as an ordered sequence of vectors, not a set. This business of $v_i\in\beta$ and $v_j^*\in\beta^*$ giving $\langle v_i,v_j^*\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$ is, frankly, nonsense. One *can* make sense of it, but it takes effort.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: After 19 hours of mathematics, I could only take the blame on me! Thank you anyway :)

Comment: 19 hours! You must be kidding! Exam coming up? Go get some sleep! All night cramming is a bad strategy, at least according to my experience. Better to be rested.

Comment: This implicitly means that you isometrically identified the dual $V^*$ with $V$, in the first place. That's actually the more delicate part of the whole thing. Once this is understood, $(v_i,v_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ says that $\beta^*=\beta$ immediately.

Comment: Just give me a minute to copy that answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $v_i,v_j\in\beta$, we know that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.  It follows that $v_j\in\beta^*$, so that $\beta\subset\beta^*$.  Now since $V$ is finite...

Comment: Damn!!!!7moretogo